# How to get sepecific element of a list of list in R?

Tags: r

I built my function (so long and complex). The output of my function is a list of two lists. To make my question clear, I built a simple example similar to my function.

```
my_func <- function(x,y){
  out1 <- list(x*y+2,x+y^2)
  out2 <- list(x^2+y-2,y-x^2)

  out <- list(out1,out2)
  return(out)
}
```

Then I got this:

```
> x <- my_func(x=c(2,3,4),y=c(5,4,7))
> x
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 12 14 30

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 27 19 53


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  7 11 21

[[2]][[2]]
[1]  1 -5 -9
```

I need to apply my function to  100 different data. Then, I will get 100 output from two lists.  How I can use `lapply` function to get specific element.

T tried this:

```
> x <- lapply(x,'[[','2')
> x
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

However, in my original function I have use the following code to access the element.

```
> x[[1]][[1]]$par  ##to get the first par (of list 1)  of the first output list. 
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000    0
[2,] 2.545870 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000    0
[3,] 3.060626 2.879527 0.000000 0.000000    0
[4,] 2.015691 2.889324 2.967189 0.000000    0
[5,] 2.862635 2.511020 2.480592 1.781923    0
```

how can I use `lapply` function to access all the `$par` of the first and second list? any help please?

Comment: Change the `'2'` to `2`.  We are subsetting by numeric index and not by character index.  If you have already named it with character vector, then it should work, otherwise, just `lapply(x, '[[', 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index used is `numeric`, we don't need the quotes.  The quotes make the `list` to check for `names` that match that character.  So,

```
lapply(x, `[[`, 2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 27 19 53

#[[2]]
#[1]  1 -5 -9
```

If we had named the sub lists, then the OP's approach would work

```
x1 <- lapply(x,  setNames, 1:2)
lapply(x1, `[[`, '2')
#[[1]]
#[1] 27 19 53

#[[2]]
#[1]  1 -5 -9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, my output is named.

Comment: This is really a new thing that I learn for `lapply` and list